# Disable automatic link creation from Matrix text field

Tags: matrix, links, text-formatting, formatting

I have Matrix field that has a `file cell` and `text cell` with the formatting set to `none`. If there is a url in the text cell when I access it a template it automatically creates a link. I can't seem to figure out how to disable this.

I'm currently on EE 2.8.1

Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is set on per-channel basis, not per-field.

Go to Admin -> Channel Administration -> Channels, click "Edit Preferences" next to your channel and set "Automatically turn URLs and email addresses into links?" to "No".

Comment: Thanks Yuri. That totally slipped my mind! I guess I would like a little more fine grain control on a setting like that.